# Getting a user's OAuth2 token for Google API

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, amazon-cognito

I work on a web app that uses cognito for authentication, and it only enables sign in from Google. I'm currently working on a feature that requires the use of the listDirectoryPeople method (https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople)

I need to authorize via the logged-in user's OAuth2 token and I can't seem to figure out how to get that from cognito without rewriting the whole login system which is not a very feasible solution. Any ideas?

I tried finding the token in the user object returned by cognito, and creating a separate auth session for the Google API.

Comment: Do you get `access_token` in `authResult` in the [callback](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/google.html#set-up-google-1.javascript) function?

Comment: show us your code,  for the most part signin is not oauth you need a specific scope to access that endpoint signin may not give you that out of the box